# Bootstrap can change sorting in Left column and right column with RWD?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I using Bootstrap V4 for my project.

I know how to create a simple RWD page.

But,I need to change sorting in Left column and right column in mobile

So I need to change upper element?  here's my code.

I found any methods to try

Can I set to these sorting only change Bootstrap and don't need use "sm-hidden"?

Content A
Menu A
Content B
Menu B
Menu C

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">

      <div class="col-12">
        Main A
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        Main B
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      
      <div class="col-12">
        Menu A
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        Menu B
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-12">
        Menu C
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi bb_inger. To make sure the problem is correctly understood, you want to be able to sort the two columns independently, but in the mobile view, the second column would be underneath, right?

When you trigger a sort (clicking a column header), you can sort the data and re-render the table. This way you can make sure the row items are consistent, even if the mobile view changes the table layout.

Comment: you need to utlise the order class in bootstap. e.g. order-md-1, then order-lg-2. Also cols should never follow cols, you need to add .row class between - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/